# Get Output Preview from QGIS ExpressionBuilder Dialog

Tags: qgis, pyqgis

I am trying to determine the data type of a field dynamically using the output preview (highlighted in the image below). However, I couldn't get a method in QGIS 2.18 API that does that.

What I am looking for is the output preview value when the preview is shown. 
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the solution. I first had to look at the ui file of QgsExpressionbuilder widget located in QGIS 2.18 repository in [GitHub](https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/blob/release-2_18/src/ui/qgsexpressionbuilder.ui). In there, I found the label that populates the output preview. The object name of this label is `lblPreview`. Then I wrote the following code to get the value.

```
tab_widget = [
  w for w in self.expressionBuilder().children()
  if isinstance(w, QTabWidget)
]
if len(tab_widget) == 0:
   return None
exp_tab = tab_widget[0].widget(0)
for label in exp_tab.findChildren(QLabel):
   if label.objectName() == 'lblPreview':
      return label.text()
```